# Limit FTP download total

Tags: ftp, quota, pureftpd

I want to be able to limit an account to download a total of X GB, then suspend the account. I'm currently using pure-ftpd w/ mysql backend and can't figure out a way to handle this. Ratio seems session-based so it's useless. Logging is also disabled for privacy and security reasons, so parsing logs to manually calculate is also not an option.

Is there a way to achieve this? What daemon can support it?

Edit:
Thanks, but no, I want to have bandwidth quota, not filesystem quotas. pure-ftpd also has support for filesystem quotas but that's not it. I want to limit bandwidth usage through FTP, so people can only download a certain amount of data, then be cut off. MySQL just handles the users, limits, etc.. instead of the passwd database.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure to understand, but you have a FTP with mysql, and you want to add quota per account? What do you use to manage the account? LDAP? Mysql?

I found [this](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Quotas.html) some time ago, not sure it's what you want but still, might help you!

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks, but no, I want to have bandwidth quota, not filesystem quotas. pure-ftpd also has support for filesystem quotas but that's not it. I want to limit bandwidth usage through FTP, so people can only download a certain amount of data, then be cut off. MySQL just handles the users, limits, etc.. instead of the passwd database.

Comment: Bandwidth quota is easy, but you'll need a third party server. You'll have to do a squid server with sarg, controlling bandwidth quota, and blocking user.

Comment: @MickeyMouse "_I want to limit bandwidth usage through FTP, so people can only download a certain amount of data, then be cut off._" That's the wrong definition of bandwidth; that's a data quota. Limiting bandwidth usage would involve giving each user a certain percentage of the available bandwidth. Let's say you have a 100 Mbps bandwidth. You could limit each user to 10 Mbps, or 1/10, of your bandwidth, but that doesn't mean total data downloaded.